# Applying column value from another table using correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables - customers and exceptions. Exceptions are applied to one or more columns in the customers table.

I am trying to rename a column based on its presence in another table.

For example: if the exception is rename customers, I need to display John Smith in lieu of John in the final output. Other names should remain intact.

Is there a better way to achieve this without using an update statement but within the same query?

```
  select id,
   (select case when b.exception = 'Rename Customers' and b.customername = 
     a.customername then b.newname else a.customername end from exception 
    b where b.activeInd = 'Y') as customername
    ,sum(wt) as wt
    from customers
     group by id
```

customers

```
     ID  customername address              wt
     1   John         123 via court         4.12
     2    Sarah        zzyx road            3.18
     3    Jill         one air force drive  2.32
     4    Julian       2218 via las pas     1.18
     5    Karto        KR38 Mount saint     1.32
```

exceptions

```
     exceptionID exception customername address oldname newname activeInd
     1  Rename Customers   John                 John    John Smith    Y
     2  Rename  address             2218 via pas 2218 via pas 2218 via 
     pas, NY  N
```

output

```
   ID customername wt
   1  null          4.12
   2  null          3.18
   3  null          2.32
   4  null          1.18
   5  null          1.32
```

expected outcome

```
   ID customername wt
   1  John Smith   4.12
   2 Sarah         3.18
   3 Jill          2.32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT c.id,
       COALESCE(en.newname, c.customername) as customername,
       c.wt
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     exceptions en
     ON en.exception = 'Rename Customers' AND
        en.oldname = c.customername AND
        en.activeInd = 'Y';
```

For additional fields, you can extend with multiple `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT c.id,
       COALESCE(en.newname, c.customername) as customername,
       COALESCE(ea.newname, c.address) as address,
       c.wt
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     exceptions en
     ON en.exception = 'Rename Customers' AND
        en.oldname = c.customername AND
        en.activeInd = 'Y' LEFT JOIN
     exceptions ea
     ON ea.exception = 'Rename Address' AND
        ea.oldname = c.address AND
        ea.activeInd = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `LEFT JOIN` the `customers` table with the `exceptions` table with the relevant criteria. Then you can use `COALESCE` to implement the replacement logic: when a matching record is found, you want to display the `newname`, else stick to the current `customername`.

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    COALESCE(e.newname, c.customername) customername,
    c.wt
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN exceptions e 
    ON  e.exception = 'Rename' 
    AND e.customername = c.customername
    AND e.activeInd = 'Y'
```

Comment: This wont work. This will only return John Smith. However, I need to display all the records but with John renamed as John Smith. Also, this wont handle where is multiple criteria for other fields. For example in the table, I have a criteria where address could be updated by turning on the flag. Lastly, in a group by, this will fail with "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error message when used in group by.

Comment: @Lucky: well, did you actually test the query? Given the sample data you provided, I suspect that it would return the expected output...